# Generate java classes from xsd with jaxb from a choice

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xsd

I use maven with jaxb to make classes out from a schema. This schema has the following choice:

```xml
<tns:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <tns:element name="video_track" type="tcore:TTrack" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <tns:element name="audio_track" type="tcore:TTrack" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</tns:choice>
```

The meening is, we want a list with `x` `audiotracks` and/or `x` `videotracks`. We need at least one of an audio or a video track!

When I generate classes with this choice I get the following code:

```java
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "audio_track", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "video_track", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<TTrack>> videoTrackOrAudioTrack;
```

This is not what we want. I think I loose informations because with the list of `TTracks` I don't know if this is a video or an audio.

So what am I doing wrong here?

In maven I use org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 version 0.8.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't lose this information.

You get a list of `JAXBElement<TTrack>`. So you can check `e.getName()` to find out if it is an audio or a video track.

You can use my [Simplify plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Simplify+Plugin#SimplifyPlugin-Aselementproperties) to get audio and video tracks in separate properties. This is not exactly the model you have in your schema, but pretty close and much easier to use.

This customization:

```
<xs:complexType name="typeWithReferencesProperty">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="a" type="someType">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <simplify:as-element-property/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="b" type="someType"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Produces:

```
@XmlElement(name = "a")
protected List<SomeType> a;
@XmlElement(name = "b")
protected List<SomeType> b;
```

The reason you get this model is the `maxOccurs` on your `choice`.

Also consider using `xs:` or `xsd:` prefixes for your XML Schema.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem with the simplify approach in a .xjb file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd" version="2.1" xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify" extensionBindingPrefixes="simplify">

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://xxx/Core.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='TStreamRecorder']/xs:sequence/xs:choice/xs:element[1]">
      <simplify:as-element-property />
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

To activate this plugin i changed my maven .pom file to:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process-xsd</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>

        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>                
          </args>

          <schemas>
            <schema>
              <url>http://xxxConfiguration.xsd</url>
            </schema>
          </schemas>

          <bindingIncludes>
            <include>schema/configBinding.xjb</include>
            <include>schema/coreBinding.xjb</include>
          </bindingIncludes>


        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This works perfect for me